# HTTPS Front End on a different host like vercel and backend node hosted on aws , connecting AWS api to front end connection refused?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-ec2

HTTPS Front End on a different host like vercel and backend node hosted on aws , connecting AWS api to front end  connection refused? it's working on local but not working on vercel hosted front end.local front end working aws api any way to fix it? my api hosted on EC2 instance ubuntu server

the solution of the problem how front end hosted react application inside work the api who has hosted on the aws ec2 instance

Comment: Please share the error you are getting. Is it CORS?